# Unsupervised many-to-one matching for two categorical variables

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, unsupervised-learning, matching

I have data on the sales of products sold at various retailers. My interest is in uniquely matching the product class to another arbitrary class.

For example, for two sets of hypothetical classes:

| Product Class | Arbitrary Class |
| --- | --- |
| Frozen Cod | Fish |
| Frozen Cod | Frozen Food |
| Fresh or Frozen Meat | Fresh Meat |
| Fresh or Frozen Meat | Frozen Food |
| Bacon | Fresh Meat |
| Bacon | Prepared Food |
| Vegetable Preparations | Prepared Food |
| Vegetable Preparations | Packaged Dry Goods |
| Vegetable Preparations | Vegetables |

I would like to be able to match them so that the product class belongs only to a single arbitrary class,

| Product Class | Arbitrary Class |
| --- | --- |
| Frozen Cod | Fish |
| Fresh or Frozen Meat | Frozen Food |
| Bacon | Fresh Meat |
| Vegetable Preparations | Prepared Food |

I say unsupervised since ideally, I do not want to provide training data for the arbitrary classes, i.e. I dont want to specify Bacon -> Fresh Meat, and then have products closest to Bacon sorted into Fresh Meat.

For each product, I have data available on the price, quantity sold, and the total sales of the product (price * quantity).

Example data,

```
set.seed(96)
product <- sample(letters, 100, replace <- T)
arbitrary <- sample(LETTERS,100,replace <- T)
price <-  rlnorm(100,meanlog <- 1)
quantity <- round(rlnorm(100,10))
sales <- price*quantity

dat <- data.frame(product,arbitrary,price,quantity,sales)
```

Thank you